# How to embed multiple node forms in drupal

Tags: 7, nodes

I have `Drupal 7` site & it has n content types. Of which 2 content types are:-

1. Product
2. Dealer

Now, I am in need to embed the above node add forms in one single form. On googling, I got to know about `Embed Node Form` module & installed it as well.
https://www.drupal.org/project/embed_node_form

But not getting how to embed multiple node forms into single form.

I didn't find any document on it.

Suggestion needed:-
Should I go with this module or develop a custom module.

Any help highly appreciated.